SIGSEGV when calling LLVMGetElementType()
I am writing my very first compiler in C, using LLVM for its backend. I stumbled upon this problem, where if I call the LLVMGetReturnType() function, it causes a segfault.
OS: WSL Debian 12
$ llvm-config --version
19.0.0git

static int generate_RETURN_IR(Stmt stmt, LLVMContextRef context,
                              LLVMModuleRef module, LLVMBuilderRef builder) {

    LLVMValueRef ret_value =
        generate_expression_IR(stmt.data.Return.value, context);

    // get the current function being built
    LLVMValueRef current_func = LLVMGetLastFunction(module);
    if (!current_func || !LLVMIsAFunction(current_func)) {
        error("return statement found outside of a function");
        return 1;
    }

    // if I comment this out, the sigsegv disappears
    LLVMTypeRef func_type = LLVMGetElementType(LLVMTypeOf(current_func));
    if (LLVMGetTypeKind(func_type) != LLVMFunctionTypeKind) {
        error("expected function type");
        return 1;
    }

    LLVMTypeRef ret_type = LLVMGetReturnType(func_type);

    // check if the return value matches the function's return type
    if (ret_value) {
        LLVMTypeRef ret_value_type = LLVMTypeOf(ret_value);
        if (ret_type != ret_value_type) {
            error("return type does not match function return type");
            return 1;
        }
    }

    LLVMBuildRet(builder, ret_value);

    return 0;
}

(the error() macro only formats and prints out the error, it does nothing that matters)
Tried commenting out the LLVMGetElementType() function, the SIGSEGV disappeared.

It's possible you caused undefined behavior earlier in the program. UB can cause random errors sometime later.
